# Laravel 5.6: is it possible to generate following query by Query Builder or Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, subquery, laravel-query-builder

I have following raw query, is it possible to create this using Laravel Query Builder or Eloquent?

```
SELECT 
SUM(records.per_hub)+SUM(records.additionl_qty) AS qty,
records.cost_price,
(records.cost_price)*(SUM(records.per_hub)+SUM(records.additionl_qty)) AS 
total
FROM
(SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS per_hub,
CEIL(COUNT(*) * 50 / 100) AS additionl_qty,
m.cost_price
FROM
orders o 
LEFT JOIN meals m
ON m.id = o.meal_id
WHERE o.shift_id = 1 
AND o.meal_id = 2 
AND o.city_id = 283 
AND o.restaurant_id = 5 
GROUP BY hub_id) records;
```

Comment: use `DB::select($query)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it as reference.

```
$sub_query = DB::table('orders as o')
      ->leftJoin('meals as m','m.id','=','o.meal_id')
      ->where('o.shift_id','=',1)
      ->where('o.meal_id','=',2)
      ->where('o.city_id','=',283)
      ->where('o.restaurant_id', '=', 5)
      ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS per_hub,CEIL(COUNT(*) * 50 / 100) AS additionl_qty,m.cost_price'))
      ->groupBy('hub_id');

    $main_query = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub_query->toSql()}) as records") )
             ->select(DB::raw('SUM(records.per_hub)+SUM(records.additionl_qty) AS qty,
                      records.cost_price,
                      (records.cost_price)*(SUM(records.per_hub)+SUM(records.additionl_qty)) AS total'))
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to create that using Laravel Query Builder, try looking up the API doc: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_addSelect

Comment: can you please give some example using above query?